# Hide/Show Product Filters containing div onClick

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

I have a website using a product filter system from a company called Manadev and am looking for a way of hiding a div containing options when an option is selected and restoring the div when the option filters are cleared.

I've contacted the developer of the product filter module but they were not very helpful in helping me find a solution.

The dev website is http://www.handcoded.co.uk/toys4cars/bmw-3-series-roof-racks.html

The code that handles the display (also see http://www.handcoded.co.uk/code.txt):

```
<?php
/**
 * @category    Mana
 * @package     ManaPro_FilterColors
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) http://www.manadev.com
 * @license     http://www.manadev.com/license  Proprietary License
 */
/**
 * Template for showing options for filter as a list of color boxes
 * @author Mana Team
 * Injected instead of standard catalog/layer/filter.phtml in Mana_Filters_Block_Filter_Attribute init() method.
 */
/* @var $this Mana_Filters_Block_Filter */
?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('mana_core')->getNamedHtml('mana_filters/markup', 'before_items', array('block' => $this)) ?>
<ol class="m-filter-colors labels <?php echo $this->getFilterClass() ?> <?php echo $this->getFilterOptions()->getIsReverse() ? 'm-reverse' : '' ?>">
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

    <li <?php echo $this->getListItemClass($_item) ?> >
        <?php if (!$this->getFilterOptions()->getDisableNoResultOptions() || $_item->getCount() || $_item->getMSelected()): ?>
            <a href="#"
            onClick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getMSelected() ? $_item->getRemoveUrl() : $_item->getReplaceUrl()) ?>');">
                <div class="m-color <?php if ($_item->getMShowSelected()): ?>selected<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $this->getFilterValueClass($_item) ?>"
                     title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?> (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)">
                    <div class="m-layer1"></div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                <div class="m-color <?php if ($_item->getMShowSelected()): ?>selected<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $this->getFilterValueClass($_item) ?>"
                     title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?> (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)">
                    <div class="m-layer1"></div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('mana_filters/display/count')) : ?>
        (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
<?php echo Mage::helper('mana_core')->getNamedHtml('mana_filters/markup', 'after_items', array('block' => $this)) ?>
```

I'm not sure whether a simple javascript show/hide is suitable enough and as this is the first time I have tried to tackle a problem like this any pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
    /**
     * @category    Mana
     * @package     ManaPro_FilterColors
     * @copyright   Copyright (c) http://www.manadev.com
     * @license     http://www.manadev.com/license  Proprietary License
     */
    /**
     * Template for showing options for filter as a list of color boxes
     * @author Mana Team
     * Injected instead of standard catalog/layer/filter.phtml in Mana_Filters_Block_Filter_Attribute init() method.
     */
    /* @var $this Mana_Filters_Block_Filter */
    ?>
    <?php echo Mage::helper('mana_core')->getNamedHtml('mana_filters/markup', 'before_items', array('block' => $this)) ?>
    <ol class="m-filter-colors labels <?php echo $this->getFilterClass() ?> <?php echo $this->getFilterOptions()->getIsReverse() ? 'm-reverse' : '' ?>">
        <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
          <?php 
$class="";
          if($_item->getMSelected()){ 
$class=str_replace('"','',str_replace('class=','',$this->getListItemClass($_item)));
   } ?>
        <li <?php echo str_replace($class,$class.' listing' , $this->getListItemClass($_item)) ?> >
            <?php if (!$this->getFilterOptions()->getDisableNoResultOptions() || $_item->getCount() || $_item->getMSelected()): ?>
                <a href="#"
                onClick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getMSelected() ? $_item->getRemoveUrl() : $_item->getReplaceUrl()) ?>');">
                    <div class="m-color <?php if ($_item->getMShowSelected()): ?>selected<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $this->getFilterValueClass($_item) ?>"
                         title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?> (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)">
                        <div class="m-layer1"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="m-color <?php if ($_item->getMShowSelected()): ?>selected<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $this->getFilterValueClass($_item) ?>"
                         title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?> (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)">
                        <div class="m-layer1"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLabel()) ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('mana_filters/display/count')) : ?>
            (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>



<?php  $i= $i+1;?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>
    <?php echo Mage::helper('mana_core')->getNamedHtml('mana_filters/markup', 'after_items', array('block' => $this)) ?>
```

add script on view.phtml

```
  <script>
    $$(".listing").each(function(el) {
                el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: I've tried to use your code but am struggling with it. Do you think you could integrate your code into the code above and re-post it

Comment: update answer check it now

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'onClick' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/handcode/public_html/toys4cars/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/manapro/filtercolors/label_one.phtml on line 22

Comment: check now updated the answer remove the error

Comment: Thanks. The 1st selected option i.e. roof type is hidden but once an option is clicked I would prefer it if the entire containing div was hidden unless the product filter is cleared.

Comment: try this may be it help

Comment: I'm afraid it has made very little difference. The entire div container for the first set of options should be hidden when a roof is selected leaving only the radio buttons below.

Comment: it is hiding the ol or li?

Comment: At the moment neither.
It should be hiding .block.block-layered-nav.block-layered-1__select_your_roof_type

Comment: now check it updated it

Comment: Again the div container is not hidden. Thanks for your efforts though

Comment: now i understand you want to hide this            
block-layered-1__select_your_roof_type        i will try again

Comment: now check this is my final try hope this will work

Comment: I tried your code which didn't work and tried removing and adding parentNode's but again no luck.

I really am grateful for you taking the time to try and help me though. Have a great day :)